# Sending HTML code to server and download it

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send some html code to server and put it in a file and download it from the browser

this is the HTML code

```
<div id="mycode">
  <p>....</p>
  <div>
    .
    .
    .
  </div>
</div>
```

When a button is clicked i try to send this html code to the server through jquery ajax, i use this code to achieve this action (i know my jquery code is missing something).

```
$(".my-button").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var htmlcontent = $("#mycode").html();

        $.ajax({
            url : "download.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {"html-code": htmlcontent},

            success : function(){

            },
            error: function(){
                //alert("something wrong");
            }
        });

    })
```

The download.php looks like this:

```
<?php


    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.html");
    header("Content-type: text/html");

    $fiile = 'test.html';


    ob_start();
    // write content
    echo $_POST["html-code"];
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    file_put_contents($file,$content);


    readfile("test.html");


?>
```

When i execute the download.php file with a simple `echo "<h1>bla bla bla</h1>"` instead of `echo $_POST["html-code"];` the download works fine, but what i want is download this file after the ajax call is done.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: _“but what i want is download this file after the ajax call is done.”_ – then you’ll have to do that _after_ the AJAX call, by assigning the download URL to `location.href`. But in half-decently modern browsers you can do that without sending the data to the server first – look into Data URIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send a form instead of using an AJAX request. You can create a hidden form, alter its input value when you need and send it using JavaScript.

As your `download.php` file has some HTTP headers that tell the browser it should download the response, you will not be redirected but asked to save the file. I could get it to work with the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mycode">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<button class="my-button">download</button>

<form id="download-form" action="download.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="html-code" value="" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".my-button").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var htmlcontent = $("#mycode").html();
    $('#download-form').find('input').val(htmlcontent).end().submit();
});
```

**download.php** (simplified just for testing purposes)

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.html");
header("Content-type: text/html");
echo $_POST['html-code'];
```

Comment: There is one more issue, echo `$_POST['html-code'];` its empty, why is that ?

Comment: I used the exact same code and I got "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" instead of an empty string.

Comment: Dear @Guilherme, my fault i miss something in the code, now its great Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the ajax will simply read the response and will not prompt any files for download since it's expecting a html/json string and will ignore the "content-disposition" of your header. In order to work, you need to a) use a hidden iframe, and set the url to file download on $.ajax response() or b) redirect the browser to the download location.